# C++ unicode tree character cout

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to write tree unicode in c++ console, but i have no idea how to do it and i couldn't find any solution here. Can someone help me with this?

There is the tree:
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F332

[image: tree]

It's for my school project. I'm creating a game.
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Please show us what you have done (share your codes) and tell us what is/are your problems

Comment: It should not be more difficult than `std::cout << "";`. But providing your console supports Unicode...

Comment: Oh, you mean a literal tree, not the data structure... how novel :P

Comment: @prapin that assumes the source file is saved as UTF-8, and the console supports UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode characters with the appropriate escape sequence:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\U0001F332" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, most toolchains should support writing the symbol directly in the code (see @prapin's comment). I'm not a fan of that, because I fear unexpected problems and believe that having non-ASCII characters in code does not make it more readable.

Comment: unicode used to be 2 characters per ascii aka 2 hex per character now the tree is using 3 hex characters for 1 symbol, don't even think C++ would keep up with those changes unless you probably using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I've tried to put just the character and your unicode but noone of this worked. It returned ­"čî▓".

Comment: @KourilProjects it means your console doesn't support UTF-8. On Windows, from my knowledge, it is not possible to directly output UTF-8 text to console: we must use `wchar_t` strings encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: @prapin Thanks! I'll take a look on that.

Comment: There are TONS of questions on StackOverflow on the topic of outputting Unicode strings to consoles.